# How I can normalize the sound on a video (mp4) file?

Tags: audio, video-conversion, mp4

I have a video(mp4) that I would like to normalize the sound on. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can try this out, Normalize audio and adjust volume for the popular video or audio sound at the same level by VolumeGain

http://bvcsoft.com/archos-video-converter.html

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Also, if you just want to recommend the software, please see http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers